# MongoDB: Return records with no coordinates in geospatial queries

Tags: mongodb

I have a 'Users' collection with a geospatial field 'location'. The 'location' is **optional** field. 
I need to write a query, when the result should started from a list of users within a radius from a provided point and finished with a list of users **without** any location.

Examples of queries:

```
db.User.find({ location: { $nearSphere: [ -104.578457, 19.684754 ], $maxDistance: 100/3963.2 } })
```

or

```
db.User.aggregate([{
    $geoNear: {
        near: [ -104.578457, 19.684754 ],
        distanceField: "distance",
        maxDistance: 100,
        distanceMultiplier: 3963.2,
        spherical: true
    }
}])
```

**My problem:**
This queries return only records with filled locations, but I also need the records without any location. I'm need something like:

```
db.User.find({ location: { $nearSphere: [ -104.578457, 19.684754 ], $maxDistance: 100/3963.2 } })
    UNION
db.User.find({ location: { $exists: false }})
```

Do you have any ideas to solve my problem? **MapReduce isn't a variant**

Comment: This is not going to be possible with a single query. The only way to include alternate results in a single query would be to use an `$or` condition, and that is not allowed with a geospatial query like `$nearSpere`. You need two queries. Depending on your language implementation this should be quite simple by running two operations in parallel and combining the results. Libraries exist for node.js for example.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thank you for your answer. The problem of two queries that it excludes the future possible pagination. This is not very good solution

Comment: @BlakesSeven [You're Goddamn Right](http://imgur.com/gallery/vB9B5).  [$or and GeoSpatial Queries](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-and-geospatial-queries)

Comment: Maybe you should explain your full case. Pagination is always possible, it just takes a little more work. But this simply is not possible with a single query. MongoDB does not do "joins" ( `$lookup` even is not really a join ), and a UNION is a join, and `$or` is not allowed.

Comment: @BlakesSeven This query will be used by a seach page, when a user can search the other users withing a radius or/and without any distanse

Comment: @user3100115 The basic case not explained there is "special indexes" ( near queries and "text" require special indexes ) that cannot be mixed with `$or`. `$geoWithin` for example does not need an index, and would not use one if combined with `$or`.

Comment: Okay. So if the "paging" is required with different results, then how else are they ranked? What determines which "near" results to show and which "no location" results to show in a page? Are they mixed or one it always meant to be at the top? Is there another field to sort on that affects the ranking. Your basic question here is it is not possible in a single query. But you are not yet asking the right question for the result you want to achieve. More information is required.

Comment: @BlakesSeven The results shoud be sorted (that's why I excluded $geoWithin). We have two types of sorting: by distance and by modify date. It's clear, that if we sort by distance, the first we show results with location. If we sort by modify date, the result will be mixed

Comment: @BlakesSeven I think if it's impossible to achive in one query, we need to revise the requirements. Any way, thank you for your answerts. It was helpful

Comment: You need to revise your question or post a more detailed explanation as a seperate one. Comments won't do enough to add a sufficient explanation. But (for example) I know of a similar application I have put together that does a similar set of mixed results with additional sorting and paging. So the "result" is possible, but there is not sufficient information on the execution here to explain the process.